# WCF REST Service save text file while hosting using Windows services

Tags: wcf

I wrote a small test WCF REST service using C#, within the WCF service, if it receive POST info from client, the WCF will collect the HTTP Request message from client and write it to a text file.  I am using Stream to collect HTTP request and using StreamWriter to write it to a text file. I can specify any folder/path for the text file.

At this point, everything is working when I host the WCF REST service using a local console app.

However, I want to host the WCF service by using Windows service, the Windows service self is fine, it can be started/stoped no issue, my issue is, when client send HTTP POST request, the WCF suppose to create the text file but I can't see the text file. I tried to search the file on the PC, I could not find it, the text file actually never generated (in my view,  Windows Service is not responsible to write the file, it is still WCF responsibility)

btw, the HTTP GET works from client (means the WCF Windows service works at least for GET).

any hints are much appreciated

Comment: What do you mean the Windows Service doesn't have a path?   Did you specify a path in the config file or in the code of the WCF service?   The Windows Service lives somewhere on the machine, so I'd expect the file to be in the executing directory if nothing else is specified.   Are you handling exceptions?  Maybe it's an access issue to the path?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did not specify the path on the WCF service, I just specify a text file name, when I use Console App to host the WCF, the text file will save in the current folder where the Console App run

Comment: on the Windows Service, I tried to run the Service from c:\test111 folder, the service installed/started, I am expecting the text file will be generated at C:\test111, but no file

Comment: I did not config anything on the app.config on both Console app and Windows Services

Comment: I am running using local admin, so the write permission should be there, I tested both c:\test111 and c:\users\myuser\my Document, no luck

I did not program anything on the exception, not sure how to check the exception if it is a Windows Service

Comment: Check in C:\test111\bin\debug (of C:\test111\bin\release if it's a release folder) as that is the executing folder.  Are you sure the WCF service started?  Without seeing some code, it's difficult to further troubleshoot.

Comment: thanks Jim, I checked those folders, no file

the code is in different PC, a little complex to copy over

the WCF service started, because the http GET is working, the POST is working too but did not write the text files